# Need some clarification in loading database in android

Tags: java, android, database

I need some inputs and suggestions from you. I have a very huge database which has around 2000 records having some information.
is it good to have another database having key value pair pointing to that huge database or XML file is enough?

Answer (score 1):

Having 2000 records is not huge. And its better to use SQLite for data operations rather than using xml file, because an xml file with 2000 pairs will make the processing slow and is resource wasting. Better use SQLite for such requirements.

Comment: Also XML is unsorted structure so searching in it is done in O(n) instead of O(logn) time

Comment: So, its not require to have a key value pair file righr?

Comment: yes you dont need it, unless you have few known keys then you may even use SharedPreferences too.